# Javascript find and replace with variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

I'm almost there with something thanks to the help of stackoverflow users. I just need a bit more help with this one.

I have a HTML page with a dynamically generated table of data which I cannot alter view. It's returned like this:

```
<tr>
<td class="name">foo<</td>
<td class="time">5:36:13</td>
<td class="avtime">0:09:36</td>
<td class="transcripts">0</td><td class="views">35</td>
<td class="percent">100</td>
</tr>
```

What I need to do is find and replace:

```
<td class="percent">$foo</td>
```

With:

```
<td class="percent"><span class="bar" style="width:$foo%"></span></td>
```

As I say I was almost there and have replacements working just not with variable values.

What I have now:

```
function replaceScript() {
var toReplace = '<td class="percent">69</td>';
var replaceWith ='<td class="percent"><span class="bar" style="width:69%"></span>  </td>';
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(toReplace, replaceWith);
}
```

Can you help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an actual element, or are you manipulating a string before adding it to the DOM?

Comment: @DavidThomas - as you can see from the reference to `document.body.innerHTML` in their code it's the actual page DOM.

Comment: ...I feel such a fool for even asking... XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than messing with the entire page HTML directly (which whacks all event handlers and forces a browser reparse of the entire page and can be fooled by different browser's re-manufacture of the HTML), I would suggest this DOM manipulation:

```
$("td.percent").each(function() {
    if (this.innerHTML == "69") {
        this.innerHTML = '<span class="bar" style="width:69%;"></span>';
    }
});
```

If you want the style width to be taken from the HTML directly and use any value you find there, then you can do it like this:

```
$("td.percent").each(function() {
    var widthVal = this.innerHTML;
    this.innerHTML = '<span class="bar" style="width:' + widthVal + '%;"></span>';
});
```

Comment: I think your on to something however I need to get the width from the content of the td.percent. Can this be done?

Comment: @user1306706 - Based on your comment - I added a second option that gets the width percentage from the previously existing HTML.

Comment: @user1306706 - there was a typo (an extra paren) in the second example that I fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Is $foo fixed? Why don't you use regular expressions?

```
var str = document.body.innerHTML;
var pattern = /($foo)/gim;
str.replace(pattern, "<span class=\"bar\" style=\"width:$1%\"></span>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegExp to search and replace as follows:

```
function replaceScript () {
  var toReplace = /<td class="percent">(\d+)<\/td>/g;
  var replaceWith ='<td class="percent"><span class="bar" style="width:$1%"></span>  </td>';
  document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace (toReplace, replaceWith);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using plain javascript

```
function replaceScript()
{
    var tbl=document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    for(var t=0;t<tbl.length;t++)
    {
        var cols=tbl[t].getElementsByTagName('TD');

        for(var i=0;i<cols.length;i++)
        {
            if(cols[i].className=="percent")
            {
                var span=document.createElement('span');
                span.className="bar";
                span.innerHTML=cols[i].innerHTML; // if you want to populate the span with td's data/innerHTML, otherwise remove this line
                span.style.width=cols[i].innerHTML+'%';
                cols[i].innerHTML='';
                cols[i].appendChild(span);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbMRM/1/).

**Edit** Or may be this one

```
function replaceScript()
{
    var tbl=document.getElementsByTagName('table');
    for(var t=0;t<tbl.length;t++)
    {
        var cols=tbl[t].getElementsByTagName('TD');
        for(var i=0;i<cols.length;i++)
        {
            if(cols[i].className=="percent")
            {
                var spanData=cols[i].innerHTML;
                cols[i].innerHTML='<span class="bar" style="'+cols[i].innerHTML+'%">'+spanData+'</span>';

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/sbMRM/2/).

Comment: Might have to be careful if there might ever be other class names on the same object with `"percent"`.  Any reason you didn't use `getElementsByClassName()`?

Comment: I think it's not supported by all browsers (if I'm not wrong).

Comment: I either use a selector library like Sizzle or the selector in jQuery or use a shim for `getElementsByClassName()`.  Browser compatibility for it is here: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname.  All save lots of coding and mistakes.

Comment: It's true, anyway, don't you consider that IE8 is still being used and it has no support for this method so may be we should not rely on className method only for this (IE8).

Comment: I said I would use either a library like Sizzle or jQuery that solves the compatibility problem or I'd use a [shim](http://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/source/browse/trunk/getElementsByClassName.js) for `getElementsByClassName()` that solves it.  My answer to this question uses jQuery because the OP tagged the question with jQuery.

Comment: @jfriend00, I've got your point but you asked me why I didn't use getElementsByClassName and it's because only for IE8 and I wanted to answer it without any dependency so I didn't use any library or shim and also OP provided an example with plain javascript so I thought it would be easy for him if he gets an answer like he's currently using.